# deciphering the start and end date encoding of an elasticsearch query in kibana dashboard

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am interested in extracting information from the dynamically generated elasticsearch in a kibana dashboard.

The elastic search has a range query as seen in the kibana documentation:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html

The documentation would have us believe that start date and end date are packaged into neat little start dates and end dates but in practice this is not the case.
Here is a representative section of the range in the elastic search request:

"range": {
                "@timestamp": {
                  "gte": 1436995517097,
                  "lte": 1436996417097
                }

**How do I make sense of the string of numbers/ how could I extract dates and time from such a string?**